# Являются ли синонимами "нигде" и "не везде"?

Tags: лексика, семантика, синонимы

Являются ли синонимами "нигде" и "не везде"?

Исходя из значений этих слов, они не являются синонимами.
И действительно, "нигде" означает "ни в каком месте", а "не везде" имеет смысл "где-то есть, а где-то нет".

Прошу специалистов и любителей филологии высказаться по этим вопросу и ответу.

Comment: На взгляд любителя, - ответ безупречен.
Сравните две фразы: «Грязь есть, но *не везде*» или «*Нигде* нет грязи».
Согласитесь, что по смыслу, эти фразы далеко не эквивалентны, скорее наоборот.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, нет - смысл разный: "нигде" означает повсеместное *отсутствие*, "не везде" предполагает *наличие* в некоторых местах при  отсутствии в остальных.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Вопрос Вам следующий: встречали ли Вы когда-нибудь - в литературе или в разговорной речи - употребление "не везде" в значении "нигде"?

Comment: Могу себе представить это как уклончивый, излишне дипломатичный ответ на вопрос "есть ли это где-нибудь" - со значением "если и есть, то не везде; скорее всего, нигде нет, но не стану утверждать - точно не знаю: вдруг где-то есть?!".

Comment: Из Вашего ответа я понимаю, что в приведенном Вами гипотетическом примере ответ "не везде" все-равно не дает значения "нигде"